# requests.get(url).json() gives JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am writing an api to get the data of an app in another app. I have my views setup to get the data from the url like:

```
import requests
user = 'hello'
pwd = 'python'
class SomeView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            r = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/foo/bar/', 
                auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, pwd))
            return HttpResponse(r.json())
        else:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success':'false', 'message':'login required '}))
```

This gives me error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/abhishek/Documents/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 799, in json
return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "/home/abhishek/Documents/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 505, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/home/abhishek/Documents/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
File "/home/abhishek/Documents/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
File "/home/abhishek/Documents/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/scanner.py", line 127, in scan_once
return _scan_once(string, idx)
File "/home/abhishek/Documents/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/scanner.py", line 118, in _scan_once
raise JSONDecodeError(errmsg, string, idx)
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have django == 1.4.5 and requests == 2.5.1 installed in my virtual environment. I have checked almost everything and now i am starting to conclude that the requests version and django version have something to do with the following traceback. I also have simplejson==3.6.5 installed in my virtual environment, which i think has no relevance. Help Please.

Comment: Why are you returning *decoded Python data* in one place and JSON in another?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with `simplejson` and its encoding. `requests` should have a built-in `json` decoder (with a specific encoding) and not call the methods of the external simplejson. But following your traceback this is what happens. Try to remove simplejson and run it again.

Comment: @a_guest: It isn't even clear to me if it is the `requests.get()` call in the view or a call *to this view*; the OP should look at `requests.get(url).content` to show us what data is being returned.

Comment: The requested url has json data. I tried uninstalling simplejson but it gives me the error JSON object could not be decoded. @MartijnPieters: The requested url is from different project and is running on different port on my server. I am requesting data from the given url  from different project.

Comment: @Dan: But apparently your JSON data is not *valid* JSON. Can you show us what `print repr(requests.get(url).content)` looks like?

Comment: `repr(requests.get(url.content)` gives me the html contents of the page. `r.status_code` gives the status code `200`.

Comment: @Dan: did you mean `repr(requests.get(url).content)`? If you get a HTML response rather than a JSON response, you need to fix *that* part.

Comment: Yes, I get html contents with divs and scripts and stuffs. So, this means , i should get json response instead of what im getting now?? Thanks for your suggestions. I will do that right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some some issues with authentication. Fixed the authentication and fixed the bugs. Thanks for help everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
import requests
from rest_framework.response import Response
...

if request.user.is_authenticated():
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/foo/bar/', 
                     auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, pwd))
    return Response(r.json())
return Response({'success':'false', 'message':'login required '})
```